# set numbers of variables for recursive make using another makefile

Tags: makefile, build, gnu-make, gnu, build-tools

I am new to makefile and I am recursively calling make to build my libraries. I need to setup "n" number of variables to build libraries. I tried adding in a file and include it in the makefile but it doesnot seems to be working.
where am I going wrong? what is the better approach to achieve this.

My main makefile :

```
      include main_setup.mk
      VER := $(shell getVersion) 
      main_setup:
               //setupsteps
      release: 
              $(MAKE) main_setup
              $(MAKE) -j8 --output_sync=target build_main
      build_main:import_a import_b import_c
      import_a: build_a
              //import_steps
      import_b: build_b
              //import_steps
      import_c: build_c
              //import_steps
      build_a: 
              cd $aDir ; $(MAKE) -j4 build
      import_a: 
              cd $bDir ; $(MAKE) -j4 build
      import_a: 
              cd $cDir ; $(MAKE) -j4 build
```

my setup file: main_setup.mk

```
plat_prefix = /main 
buildroot = $(plat_prefix)/submain/another

ifneq ('$(JAVA_PATH)','')
export PATH := $(JAVA_PATH):$(PATH)
endif

export BUILD_ROOT = $(buildroot)

ifneq ('$(LOCAL_BUILD_ROOT)','')
export BUILD_ROOT= $(LOCAL_BUILD_ROOT)
endif

export VAR1 = 1
export VAR2 = 2
export VAR3 = 3
export VAR4 = 4
export PATH := /var/main/bin:$(VAR1)/tools/bin:$(VAR2)/tools/bin:$(VAR3)/tools/bin:$(PATH)
```

**Error :**

```
/bin/bash: getVersion: command not found

which getVersion

/var/main/bin/getVersion
```

**UPDATED THE QUESTION**

Comment: Can you show us your error? What exactly does not work?

Comment: Thank you @Vroomfondel , my problem is I want the variables to be set for child process. example, ```make -j4 build_a``` should be able to access the PATH variable set in main_setup.mk

Comment: Please write this down in the question, also how this error does represent itself. In the makefile `build_a` write a "$(info $(PATH))` at the top to check if it really didn't receive the exported variable.

Comment: @Vroomfondel , there is no error. But when I try to build libraries, variables which I assigned/PATH variables are not accesible, example "getPath" file which is in the ```$(VAR1)/tools/bin```. Which is called in ```build_a```, i get "Command not found" error

Comment: Please include the complete error log. It is impossible to gauge what is happening, if half the story is missing. See also [MCVE]

Comment: Is your `$(VAR1)` absolute? Note that you change your current working directory with `cd`, so relative paths will change and not work.

Comment: Are you using GNU make?  Also what shell are you using.   There are certain environments where make doesn't update the environment when you set `PATH`.   As @Vroomfondel suggested, add an `$(info path is $(PATH))` right after the include to see if `PATH` indeed has the correct value.   If it does, try setting `SHELL := /bin/bash`, or explicitly set `PATH=$(PATH)` in the recipe line to see if it resolves things.

Comment: @HardcoreHenry i need to add /bin/bash to setup file or the main make file?

Comment: I'm suggesting you try it to understand what your issue is.   If your shell/make combination do not support setting PATH in make, then you would need to find an alternative (such as setting PATH on the recipe line, or switching to the bash shell, etc).